# Marking F# method with `async` modifier

Tags: f#

I am trying to implement a method in F# that would be used from C# in `async .. await` manner.
Here is the stub:

```
[<Extension>]
static member DoWorkAsync(value : MyValueType): Task<MyOtherType> =
    task {
        // do something and return
    }
```

However, when I consume this method from C# I get

> The 'await' expression can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the 'async' modifier

What would be the way to mark F# method with `async` modifier?

Comment: There's something wrong at C# side. Can you share code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the C# code, but is sounds like you're doing something like:

```
public Task<MyOtherType> FooAsync(MyValueType v)
{
    var v = await DoWorkAsync(v);
    return new MyOtherType(v); 
}
```

while the following would work:

```
public async Task<MyOtherType> FooAsync(MyValueType v)
//     ^^^^^
{
    var v = await DoWorkAsync(v);
    return new MyOtherType(v); 
}
```